# Remove default padding from FlexibleSpace title

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

Code:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 200.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("Flexible title")),
        background: Image.asset("assets/chocolate.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(_buildChildren())),
  ],
);
```

Why there is a default padding in the title. I used `Container` to bring contrast so that the margin can be visible easily. Even I tried using `centerTitle: false` and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 7):

You can now use the `titlePadding` attribute like so:

```
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('Home'),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                start: 0.0,
                bottom: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

In `_FlexibleSpaceBarState` in method `build`:

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
        start: effectiveCenterTitle ? 0.0 : 72.0,
        bottom: 16.0
      )
```

So, there is no way to remove this bottom padding except customization

For testing I've changed one string in source code to `bottom: 0.0` and this padding disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is something playing with a file that doesn't belong to your project. I know I can edit this file too but I was hoping for a better solution that can be implemented on my code side. So, I won't accept this answer however I will give +1 for sure.

Comment: Another way is build your custom FlexibleSpaceBar

Comment: Yes, I do know that, there is always a way to build your own Widget by extending the class and override the method you care about. I thought Flutter team would have added some sort of property that should let user specify padding of their choice.

Comment: As I said - it's hardcoded on state class. So there are only two these options

Answer (score 0):

not centered, `EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start 0, bottom: 16)` otherwise.

final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;